# Reprogramming Garage Door Remote

Tags: doors, garage

I've been using a Beninca TWV remote (Shown below) to open my home garage door for the last 3/4 years without any problems, until this morning when the remote stopped working. *To be clear I replaced the battery last night, which is the only thing I could imagine causing this.*

I've found a few videos/articles online that show how to program a new remote using either the base unit/receiver or an existing working remote (My girlfriend's remote works fine). There is only a single red button on the board (Shown below) & two red LEDs (Most that I've seen online seem to have just one LED).

The advice that I followed was from the manufacturer's manual for the remote, which said I should press the "Program" or "PGR" button, press a button on the remote within 10 seconds, wait 10 seconds and the remote should be working. I've tried that a few times but it's not working.

I will try to program using my girlfriend's remote when she's back, but I just wanted to see if anyone had any advice as to how I should proceed & if anyone recognized the board shown below.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Board]

[image: Remote]

Comment: Can you find the make and manufacturer of the card?  I think the remote is a universal remote.  You should find out how to clear the memory of the garage door control board first, then start over.  I'm guessing you are out of memory, or have exceeded the number of channels and the channel numbers don't rollover.

Comment: @N8sBug Unfortunately I can't - that's something I was hoping to get off this board. I bought the property with this installed so I'm hoping to get in touch with the installer but most likely won't get a reply until next week.

Comment: Is that a red push button on the lower 1/4th of the board? I'm sure it's probably not something so simple, but could that be the learn button?

Comment: @Derrick Hey - That's the button that I pressed as mentioned in the original post, unfortunately it did nothing :( I'm curious as to why the board has two red LEDs, though. Perhaps I need to hold the button to get it into "learning mode" or something similar.

Comment: Usually you do hold the button down on the board then when it blinks/flashes after 10 seconds or so you hold down the button on the remote until the board blinks/flashes to acknowledge the learned channel.

Comment: @N8sBug Thanks - I'll give that a go in an hour or so. I'm also intrigued by the 6 switches to the right of the board.

Comment: Been thinking about this one a lot.  How's it coming?  Could you add a photo of the assembled garage door opener unit?  Have to ask: are you sure there isn't a serial on there somewhere?  Logically, if there is only one button, there are only a limited number of combos of input that the control board button and your remote could produce.  It's tedious but is achievable, look to other manufacturers for typical input arrangements to program.

Comment: Managed to get in touch with the guys who installed it who said that adding new remotes to the receiver had been disabled so I've been able to get a new remote through them, luckily. Thanks so much for your interest in my problem - genuinely appreciate it :)